# Is there any disadvantage of using pngquant for my PNGs on websites (except losing some colors)

Tags: image, png, pngquant

I have been using pngoo(pngquant) for most of my website projects during last two years since the size is drastically lower in comparison to traditional PNGs and the loss of color is mostly hardly noticeable even for trained eye.

**However, are there any disadvantages of compressing PNGs by this algorhitm?
Are those PNGs also progressive?**

**Are they slower/same speed/faster to render for browser?**

Comment: Render times nowadays are completely irrelevant; any brick of a cell phone has the processing power to render an image faster than it can be downloaded. The only real disadvantage I can see is that people downloading said images will generally expect PNGs to be the original non-degraded image.

Comment: I use png to create dynamic animations with libraries like jquery or GSAP(rotating, scaling images, etc.). Yes, there is a lot of processing power in todays devices, but I have experienced that on some low-end devices without dedicated graphic card, some complex animations were slow and I had to simplify them down.

Comment: Also, I live in region where majority ppl doesnt have high-end smartphones like Apple/Samsung or laptops.

Comment: Seems irrelevant. Graphics cards are generally not the part that handles decompression anyway.

Comment: Okay, didnt knew that